# Bootstrap Horizontal Menu

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, nav, responsive

I am trying to create a wordpress website using the Bootstrap framework, is there a way to create a horizontal sub menu? I am already using the Walker class for dropdowns. But I would like the menu to look like [this](http://i62.tinypic.com/2q8bt5u.gif)

[dropdown example image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ4Jp.gif)

And being mobile responsive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are proficient with css you could use bootstrap dropdowns and then customise the css to make the drop down part 100% width etc just like you would if you make a menu without bootstrap. Within that you could probably implement the bootstrap grid system to maintain responsiveness if you wish, however you would need to consider what happens when the user enters mobile view... You would need media queries one way or another as you wont want the menu horizontal on a small screen. The grid system would help with this but when I have done similar things I still needed a few media queries.

The alternative is to look for a jquery plugin to achieve this effect, or begin learning javascript. But unless they do everything you want its probably not going to be much benefit seen as though you already have the actual drop down functionality there with bootstrap. Sorry i've not given you an explicit answer but this should help you figure out how you want to tackle it.

Comment: Actually, I did try it out and since it didnt work, I decided to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you add just "display: -webkit-inline-box;" to the ul class dropdown-menu you should see the menu change to the way you describe wanting it - not saying thats all that needs to be done like I stated above - but it just takes some time and fiddling about with.

If you aren't already doing so, using "inspect element" in a browser is a quick way to test css changes. Its how I figure out what I'm going to do next if not sure about things.

I hope this helps you.

[See Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwbnh.png)